# Get Action name from URL inside ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, custom-action-filter

I am writing custom filter attribute inherited from `ActionFilterAttribute` class in `ASP.Net MVC`. I want to get name of action from url, I tried

```
ControllerContext controllerContext = new ControllerContext();
controllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

but there is no item in `controllerContext.RouteData.Values`, hence giving me null reference error. Is any other way to get the same?

Comment: You creating a **new** controller context. Use `string actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];` in the `OnActionExecuting` method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following

```
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

        string action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        string controller = filterContext.Controller.GetType().Name;

    }
```

Comment: Though I had an answer before you posted, but your answer looks better, cleaner, simpler and one liner :)

Comment: hi, if possible can you answer issue i am facing in asp mvc cache , [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704618/asp-mvc-caching-static-contents-gives-500-internal-server-error) is the question. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

```
var rd = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
string actionName = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
```

worked for me.